# Getting java.io.IOException: CreateProcess: c:\Windows\System32\My_exe 1 error=2

Tags: java, windows-7, windows-xp, createprocess, runtime.exec

I am getting

```
java.io.IOException: CreateProcess: c:\Windows\System32\My_exe 1 error=2
```

when I am trying to run my app which needs to execute My_exe.exe. I am running my app in

Wepshere 6.1 server and OS is Windows 7 64 bit and the editor is RAD 7.5.4.

The PATH is set to `C:\Windows\System32`. When I run it from dos prompt - no errors.

Same app runs good on Windows XP.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you print the full stack trace, or that's all you get?

Comment: error=2 means that the file is not found. Show the real code and the complete stacktrace.

Answer (score 3):

You don't say what you are doing to run your application, but if you're using Runtime.exec you need to reference "My_exe.exe", not just "My_exe".

Comment: thanks for your reply but its My_exe.exe sorry about the typo.And yes I am using Runtime.exec

Comment: Here is the stacktrace I'm getting :java.io.IOException: CreateProcess: My_exe.exe 1 error=2
 at java.lang.ProcessImpl.create(Native Method)
 at java.lang.ProcessImpl.<init>(ProcessImpl.java:108)
 at java.lang.ProcessImpl.start(ProcessImpl.java:56)
 at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:466)
 at java.lang.Runtime.exec(Runtime.java:607)
 at java.lang.Runtime.exec(Runtime.java:480)
 at my.research.service.TestService.main(TestService.java:190)

Answer (score 0):

windows 7 x64 does not have command.com since it is a 16bit application
i had the same problem, and a friend of mine found out a brilliant sollution

copy cmd.exe and rename the copy as command.com, put it in the path

Problem solved!!!